# Adding a new tab in a web brower supplied with VFP that uses the IE control

Tags: webbrowser-control, visual-foxpro

I am  using a class supplied with VFP that uses the IE7 control  _webview to open up a web browser and it does not have a function to add a new tab withen the browser , if I am clicking on link in a current page it will open it in  IE , is there a way that the new page should open up on the foxpro browser ,

and How can I add a new tab in the  browser for a new search

also   is there a class  that will open up a web browser in foxpro based on a more updated internet broweser

Answer (score 1):

There is no tab in the control. you need to create new tabs in response of [the NewWindow2 event](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/184876/en-us) from the webbrowser control, put a new webbrowser control on the tab, then tell the event that the new webbrowser control should be used to display the new window. Your event handler looks like this:

```
LPARAMETERS ppdisp, cancel

*creating new tab

newTab.ADDOBJECT("Olecontrol1", "OLEControl", "shell.explorer.2")

With newTab
  .olecontrol1.Top = 0
  .olecontrol1.Width = .Width
  .olecontrol1.Left = 0
  .olecontrol1.Height = .Height
  .olecontrol1.visible = .T.
  .olecontrol1.RegisterAsBrowser = .T.
  .Visible = .T.
Endwith
ppDisp = newTab.olecontrol1.Object
```

By default the webbrowser control operates in IE7 mode. To opt-in to a new version, add a [FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ee330730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#browser_emulation) registry key in your program's installer.